# How to loop through days of a month?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to loop through all days of a month. I have the year and month value within the constructor method.

```
for (DateTime indexDay = DateTime(this.year,this.month,1); indexDay.month == this.month; indexDay.add(new Duration(days:1))) {
   print(indexDay.toString());
}
```

It makes an infinite loop. Index Day is not increasing. What is wrong with my statements?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`indexDay.add(new Duration(days:1))` doesn't modify `indexDay` but returns a new `DateTime` with `newDateTime.day == indexDay.day + 1`. Try the following instead:

```dart
for (DateTime indexDay = DateTime(this.year,this.month,1); 
     indexDay.month == this.month; 
     indexDay = indexDay.add(Duration(days:1))) {
   print(indexDay.toString());
}
```